# How to control all objects within a group in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to use classes and adding sprites to groups, this works fine but I don't know how to refer to everything in a group, I tried to look this up but I'm still stuck, I might need to use def functions or whatever inside the class but I couldn't get that to work, here my code:

```
import random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screensurf = pygame.Surface((800,600))
screensurf.fill((255,255,255))

class rain(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos): 
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((1,3))
        self.image.fill((30,30,30))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x_pos
        self.rect.y = y_pos
        self.movey = 0
        self.movex = 0
        self.rect.x += 0 
        self.rect.y += 1


RainGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
for RainDrop in range(100):
    RainDrop = rain(random.randrange(0,800), 400)
    RainGroup.add(RainDrop)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    RainDrop.rect.y += 1

        
    screen.blit(screensurf,(0,0))
    RainGroup.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Basically it's only moving one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a `.update`  method in your class, it will be called by Pygame when you call `group.update()`. Otherwise, just loop through your sprites by using the group with a for loop:

```
for sprite in RainGroup:
    # do things to sprite here
    ...
```